# Convergence of improper integrals of the second kind (wrt the Tom Apostol's definition)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The section $10.23$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$ begins with saying that the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ until this section was introduced with the restriction that $f$ is defined and bounded on a finite interval $[a, b]$.

Later, in the same section $10.23$, he defines the improper integral of the second kind as:

> Suppose $f$ is defined on the half-open interval $(a, b]$, and assume that the integral $\int_x^b f(t)dt$ exists for each $x$ satisfying $a < x \le b$. Define a new function $I$ as follows: $I(x) = \int_x^b f(t)dt$ if $a < x \le b$.
> The function $I$ so defined is called an improper integral of the second kind and is denoted by the symbol $\int_{a+}^b f(t)dt$. The integral is said to converge if the limit $\lim_{x \to a+} I(x) = \lim_{x \to a+} \int_x^b f(t) dt$ exists and is finite. Otherwise, the integral $\int_{a+}^b f(t)dt$ is said to diverge.

My question is why is the definition given with respect to the integral, instead of the integrand? More concretely, if I prove that $\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = L$, and otherwise $f$ is continuous and defined on $a < x \le b$, could I also conclude that the integral converges? Could you provide a proof of that using the existing definitions?

The problem is that I don't know how to prove that, because both of the definitions do not seem to fit that well. Namely, the first definition requires $f$ to be defined at $a$, and the second definition requires me to compute the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "$\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = L$, and otherwise $f$ is continuous and defined on $a < x \le b$" then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and then by the fundamental theorem on calculus the integral converges ($I$ is even defined and differentiable on $[a,b]$).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, and I had the same idea in mind how to justify that, but I would appreciate if you could provide a valid reason why it's fine. That point difference invariance was just briefly mentioned in section $1.12$, page $65$, so I wondered if a more explicit treatment was needed or we could take that as a part of the integral definition.

Comment: The point difference invariance mentioned p. 65 has nothing to do with this convergence result (which is a true theorem and not part of the definition). I cannot see what "valid reason" you are missing. The fundamental theorem on calculus is a good one. If you prefer: since $f$ is continuous on $(a,b]$ and has a (finite) limit at $a,$ it is bounded, say $|f|\le M.$ Then, you can apply the "limit comparision test" (mentioned in section 10.23) to $0\le F\le G$ with $F=f+M$ and $G=2M:$ $\int_{a^+}^bG$ obviously converges hence so does $\int_{a^+}^bF$ and therefore also $\int_{a^+}^bf.$

Comment: Thanks! I suppose $G$ is the function $f$, except that $G(a) = \lim_{x \to a+} f(x)$. The link I'm missing is the last part, because I haven't seen a proof nor definition which would mention that a finite number of point differences of integrands are irrelevant for the integral value. In other words, why is $\int_{a+}^b F$ = $\int_{a+}^b f$? Is it because $a^+ > a$ by definition, so on that integration interval $F$ and $f$ are equal?

Comment: No, $G\ne f.$ I wrote $G=2M$ and $F=f+M$ (I just translated the functions for $F$ to be non-negative like in Apostol's comparision test). $\int_{a+}^b f$ is not equal to $\int_{a+}^bF$ but the convergence of one is equivalent to the convergence of the other one because the difference is simply $(b-a)M.$

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good. And the integral is defined, because $a^+ > a$, and that was the main thing I was missing before. Thank you for the follow up and the added explanation!

Comment: $a^+>a$ means nothing. $a^+$ in itself has no existence. $\int_{a^+}^b$ means $\lim_{x\to a^+}\int_x^b,$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ means $\lim_{x\to a, x>a}.$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!